# Random freezes in Ubuntu: Seeking a diagnosis method

Tags: 16.04, gnome, performance, freeze

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with a powerfull hardware (12GB RAM, 512GB SSD, Core i7 CPU). However, **the system randomly freezes for 5-10 seconds**.

It seems that a process is blocking everything, or some core component of the system or Gnome 3 has a problem, e.g. an undefinite loop happens, and then some faulty proecss is killed by a timeout; something like that...

When a freeze happens, the mouse works (sometimes) but Gnome halts working for a few minutes. This is very disturbing, and happens in many applications such as Chrome, VMware (running windows), and Telegram Desktop.

Questions:

1. Is it common among Ubuntu 16.04 users?
2. How should I find out the cause of random freezes? Which log files should I look into?

Note: If the disk was an HDD, I would have diagnosed it as a seek-time problem or a result of too much swap. However, my disk is SSD and the swap is disabled, so... ?!

Any ideas?

Comment: Note, it is not common, I used it for a few months without a problem

Comment: Do you have a Kaby Lake CPU?

Comment: Also, do you have a dedicated GPU?

Comment: @AndroidDev  No, The CPU is Core i7-6700 @ 3.40GHz. Also, the GPU is NVIDIA NVS 310. Is it shared?

Comment: @UbuntuUser I know that it is not common. I want a method for diagnosing the cause of the problem.