# HP15 Ubuntu 18.04 freezes

Tags: 18.04, hp, radeon, freeze, amdgpu

So I got a new HP15 (db0xxx) laptop at work, but unfortunately, it occasionally freezes. Freezes happen at random moments, sometimes after working for several hours and sometimes several days.

Mouse and keyboard are dead, can't start up the console, music that was playing is stuck. Sometimes I can kill the system with alt+sysreq+REISUB, sometimes I can't and I have to shut down by the power button.

I've done some research on the internet and the only suggestion I could find was that it may be a hardware issue. Processor is Ryzen 3, GPU Radeon Vega Mobile. Running Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried checking the logs, but I'm not sure what to look for since I'm new to Ubuntu. Any suggestions or solutions are appreciated.

Update 6/11
The following errors look similar:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1562530
https://community.amd.com/thread/228365

Following suggestions in these threads, I tried:
- Resetting BIOS,
- Several kernels,
- Editing grub parameter: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash idle=nomwait"

I'm not 100% sure if I edited the grub setting correctly, it was quite hard to find a basic explanation. It seems like the freezes happen less frequently, but they are not gone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freeze after login Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030060/freeze-after-login-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: The dupe suggestion seems to be something about nvidia? That's not going to help here, graphics card is Radeon...

Comment: This is about tracking down an intermittent bug so may not be a good fit here, but it's a [frequently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880526/random-freezes-in-ubuntu-seeking-a-diagnosis-method) [asked](https://askubuntu.com/q/850470/12864) [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065819/ubuntu-18-04-freezee-or-hang). Is there a canonical answer for this? The "What to do when Ubuntu freezes" isn't helpful here, OP already knows what to do.

Comment: @TomBrossman, your first link is not similar at all, since the freezes are close to log-in. The second link might be, although both software and hardware are quite different, so I have no idea how this might be the same problem. The third link is not very specific about how freezes happen, so it's hard to judge.

Comment: My notebook runs kubuntu 18.04 on an i7 with Intel graphics and occasionally locks up like this, so it might not be a hardware specific issue. I think the issue is older than 18.04 as well.

Comment: @Joe, see my 6/11 update. I found some similar issues which indeed have different hardware. Wondering how to fix the software issue though.